# Illustrator: check if object is colliding

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm working on a large map and there are a lot of text objects where some of them collide for some reason. Now I'd like to figure out if there is a method where I can see if objects collide with each other. So that all text objects that has another text object colliding should be selected or highlighted in some way.

Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't it visible to you which objects are colliding? I assume you're asking about overlapping objects. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: It's a huge document with hundreds of text objects. Some of them are colliding, ie lying on top of each other, and it's hard to find all the colliding objects.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no. Illustrator offers no mechanism to detect collisions.

You *might* be able to formulate a script, but I honestly don't know if even that is possible.